# IIS + PHP + MySQL returns 500 - Internal server error

Tags: php, mysql, iis, iis-7

We're building a new server and using IIS 7. PHP pages a served just fine and dandy, but the second we use any code to access a MySQL database, the page hangs for a good minute and serves the following error:

```
Server Error

500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.
```

Our database.php config file is configured correctly, so I can't figure out what might be doing this. MySQL seems to be properly installed as well.

Any ideas? Googling hasn't lead me anywhere useful.

Comment: Are there any error logs left behind somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your MySQL-Extension of PHP is not loaded correctly. Is it included in the php.ini? If so, please just take a look in the php_error.log. There should be an entry there. Please post it here

Answer (score 0):

Rdp to your IIS web server
Right click on the folder where your site contents in and click on properties
go to security tab > advance > click on Edit > click on add > and enter domain users and click ok.
Now click on Edit and give full control or modify or read
Now select "Replace all existing inheritable permissions on all descendants with inheritable permission from this object
Click on apply, let it finish the process and click on Ok and ok.

This will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change the memory_limit variable in you php.ini file.  I had a similar problem where I was doing a very large select query.

On a development server the query would run fine, but on the live server it would throw a 500 error.

The difference turned out to be that my live server's memory_limit was set at "64M" whereas  the dev server was "512M".  I bumped the live server up to 512M and that resolved the problem.